# Passing two Variables for a ListView Android

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, listadapter

I'm developing a Item QR Scanner application using Zxing Scanner Library and i want to enter scan data into a listview. So i want to enter ItemName and ItemPrice into ListView after scanning the item. To differentiate itemName and itemPrice from scanner result(plain text) i used string tokenizer class then i can get itemName and Price seperately.

The solution should be while a user scanned an item it should display item Name and item Price separately in the list View. The problem is how to use a String and Integer can use to implement this system.

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(scanRes, ":");
   itmName = tokenizer.nextToken();
   itmPrice = Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

And i'm passing the result to a String name "scanRes" (mentioned above code) through this statement.

```
qrResult.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
String scanRes = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
```

i want to view the assigned values in two variables mentioned above(itmName  and itmPrice) into a ListView. I have implemented a solution bt it needs String array to pass values. Bt i need to pass the values saved in this two Variables. I'll post below the solution i have created. Thanks a lot if anyone can tell what are the things i have to change in the Code.

This is the code for **Scanner Activity** Class. And its giving an error for the "onItemClick" method at the bottom.

```
public class QRScanMenu extends Activity {
String itmName;
Integer itmPrice;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.qrscannermenu);

    HandleClick handleClick = new HandleClick();
    findViewById(R.id.QRButton).setOnClickListener(handleClick);
    findViewById(R.id.ExitButton).setOnClickListener(handleClick);



}

private class HandleClick implements View.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View arg0){
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            switch (arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.QRButton:
                    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                    break;

                case R.id.ExitButton:
                    Intent i = new Intent(QRScanMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
            }
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
            showDialog(QRScanMenu.this, "No Scanner Application Found", "Download Scanner Application?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }
}

private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity activity, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence btnYes, CharSequence btnNo){
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(btnYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(btnNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent intent){
    if (reqCode == 0){
        TextView qrStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        TextView qrResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.qrItmList);

        if(resCode == RESULT_OK){
            qrStatus.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
            qrResult.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
            String scanRes = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(scanRes, ":");
            itmName = tokenizer.nextToken();
            final String[] newd = new String[1];
            newd[1]=itmName;
            itmPrice = Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken());
            Integer[] newI = new Integer[1];
            newI[1]=itmPrice;

            customList adapter = new customList(QRScanMenu.this, newd, newI);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    Toast.makeText(QRScanMenu.this, "You Clicked at "+newd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });



            //adapter.add(itmName);
            //adapter.add(itmPrice);
        }
        else if (resCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            qrStatus.setText("Press QR Scan button to Scan Item");
            qrResult.setText("Scan Cancelled");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've used this String Arrays for Testing purposes. Not sure will they work or not.

```
final String[] newd = new String[1];
newd[1]=itmName;
itmPrice = Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken());
Integer[] newI = new Integer[1];
newI[1]=itmPrice;
```

**And this Code for the List**

```
public class customList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final String[]itmName;
private final Integer[]itmPrice;
public customList(Activity context, String[]itmName, Integer[]itmPrice){
    super(context, R.layout.columnview, itmName);
    this.context = context;
    this.itmName = itmName;
    this.itmPrice = itmPrice;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.columnview, null, true);
    TextView txtViewName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itmCol);
    TextView txtViewPrice = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceCol);
    txtViewName.setText(itmName[position]);
    txtViewPrice.setText(itmPrice[position]);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

[image: This is the error i'm getting for now..]

This is the XML Code for **columnView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itmCol"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceCol"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</TableRow>
```

And this is the code for **QR scanner activity class**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linLayout1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/QRButton"
        android:text="QR Scan"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ExitButton"
        android:text="Back Main"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/statusText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linLayout1"
    android:text="Press QR Scan Button to Scan Items"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/resultText"
    android:text="Ready to Scan"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/statusText"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/qrItmList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/resultText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ListView>
```

Comment: You could make an `Item` class and modify your adapter to extend `ArrayAdapter<Item>`

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: i've updated the question..

Comment: Did you attempt my answer? The error is the `?` should be `String` but you'll get another error as you are attempting to use a local variable in an anonymous class.

Comment: @RobVoisey ok give me a minute..ill give a try and tell you!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a new object to hold your two items

```
public class Product {
    String name;
    int price;
 }
```

Then you make an ArrayAdapter for you items.

```
public class MyAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private final Activity context;
    public customList(Activity context, Product[] products){
        super(context, R.layout.columnview, products);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.columnview, null, true);
        TextView txtViewName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itmCol);
        TextView txtViewPrice = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.priceCol);
        txtViewName.setText(getItemAtPosition(position).name);
        txtViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(getItemAtPosition(position).price]));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Your onClickListener would then be:

```
listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<Product> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            Toast.makeText(QRScanMenu.this, "You Clicked at "+ parent.getItemAtPosition(position).name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: i've already defined that two variables in QR ScanMenu Class.. Do i have to create another class and define it??

Comment: @Miuranga if you already have another class with those two, you can use that class instead.

Comment: yeahh i'm already using them.. can i know why its getting an error in onClickItem method??

Comment: I answered it before: "The error is the ? should be String but you'll get another error as you are attempting to use a local variable in an anonymous class". Unless there is a new error?

Comment: i replaced that '?' mark to String bt its giving the same error.. anyway itmName, and itmPrice already defined in same class.. :/

Comment: sounds like you've defined itmName and itmPrice twice... anyway, I think the remainder are general code errors which are outside the scope of the question, these comments are not meant for general discussion; I suggest you read up on ListViews here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html.

Comment: ok i fixed the error in onClickButton() method.. now when i scanned an item the program getting force closed..

Answer (score 0):

```
final String[] newd = new String[1];
newd[1]=itmName;
```

Size of the String array is 1 but the arrayindex starts with 0. you are adding itmName into the 1st position.

```
itmPrice = Integer.valueOf(tokenizer.nextToken());
Integer[] newI = new Integer[1];
newI[1]=itmPrice;
```

Size of the Integer array is 1 but the arrayindex starts with 0. you are adding newI into the 1st position.

Obviously, you will get ArrayIndexOutofboundsException!

Answer (score -1):

i cannot see any custom xml for list item in your code.
create a custom xml for list view item. and then inflate it using inflater

Comment: he does so in this line `View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.columnview, null, true);` Downvoted as doesn't address the question.